# Angular: Dynamically change <ng-outlet> content

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component with a ng-outlet. Now I try to set the outlet content dynamically. My first try was it to just set the innerText property of the DOM-Element, but then all other content of the components template get lost. Maybe I use a completely wrong way, I'm very new to Angular.

Here is my component:

```js
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ks4-error-output',
  templateUrl: './error-output.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error-output.component.styl']
})
export class ErrorOutputComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

And here the template:

```html
<div [hidden]="content.innerText==''">
  <span>Error:</span>
  <span #content><ng-content></ng-content></span>
</div>
```

I tried to set the content like this (in this case clear the ng-outlet content):

```html
<form (ngSubmit)="error.innerText=''; ...">...</form>
...
<ks4-error-output #error id="errorOutput"></ks4-error-output>
```

But then the complete content is lost. Same thing if I try to set some content this way. I didn't find anything with google, every time I try searching, google only founds router-oulet things.

Answer (score 0):

ngOutlet is a AngularJS directive. If you are using Angular 2 or 4 (Which I assume you are considering you have @Component in your code), you can use router-outlet to set components to show. It allows for static/dynamic templating using static/dynamic routes.

An alternative without routes is to use the [dynamic component loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader). It also let you have multiple directives with dynamic component on the same page while router-outlet technically doesn't allow this.

Comment: I don't want to load a component but a simple text

Comment: Then you can simply use the innerHTML binding `[innerHTML]="theHtmlString"`

Comment: Can I than change the text dynamicly

Comment: And this wouldn't solve my problem that this text isn't printed inside the ng-content container